# How to use php echo without quotes to echo html code?

Tags: php, html, decoding

I'm trying to print out some html code which isn't stored as a simple string so I need to decode it before echo-ing, my problem is when I echo a decoded value I keep getting these quotes and they are ruining the output, this is how it looks:

```
<div>
"<h1 class="ql-align-center">TEST</h1>"
</div>
```

so because of these quotes " h1 failes to form and it prints out as a text and not as an html code.
So i'm wondering is it possible to print as html code meaning there is no quotes "" ?

this is the php code that it generates it like this

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($singleEmail['camp_desc'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

also this is the database value of 'camp_desc' that has to be encoded before being printed

```
&amp;lt;h1 class=&amp;quot;ql-align-center&amp;quot;&amp;gt;TEST&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;
```

and the output of php code above for encode is

```
<h1 class="ql-align-center">TEST</h1>
```

but since I'm using echo to print.... php wraps it with quotes and `<h1>` tag becomes a plain text instead of html element

Comment: Please show us the PHP code that is generating this output - we can't help you fix the problem when we can't see the code that is causing it!

Comment: @FluffyKitten hello, sorry I edited with php code

Comment: And can you also show us the value it is working on? Add this to the code before the echo, and edit your question to include the output: `var_dump($singleEmail['camp_desc']);`

Comment: @FluffyKitten hey, sorry I edited again with more info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where the quotes are coming from - the code you have in your question doesn't add extra quotes so they are coming from somewhere else.

However if you want the HTML string to be rendered as HTML instead of displaying the tags as text, you can do the following:

Starting with this value in your variable:

`&amp;lt;h1 class=&amp;quot;ql-align-center&amp;quot;&amp;gt;TEST&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;`

> displayed as: &lt;h1 class=&quot;ql-align-center&quot;&gt;TEST&lt;/h1&gt;

...you can use `html_entity_decode` to decode it which will give us the following output, i.e. it converts it into a string that will display as plain text HTML when you echo it:

`&lt;h1 class=&quot;ql-align-center&quot;&gt;TEST&lt;/h1&gt;`

> displayed as: <h1 class="ql-align-center">TEST</h1>

...now we need to decode *this* to turn it into the HTML elements that will be displayed as a H1 tag in the page:

`<h1 class="ql-align-center">TEST</h1>`

> displayed as: TEST

**Code:** To do this, you need to call `html_entity_decode` *twice* before it will display the string as HTML elements:

```
<?php  
$htmlstr = html_entity_decode($singleEmail['camp_desc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo html_entity_decode($htmlstr, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works, I would never guess i needed to use it twice xD,

Comment: I know! It was when I `var_dump`ed the values that I saw what what happening. PS, *wo*man, not man :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to replace those quotes when echo-ing them?

Like you make regular expression to replace it or you make a function that replaces the two parts you want like `str_replace('”<', '<', $yourDecodedHtml)`,
`str_replace('>”', '>', $yourDecodedHtml)`

Comment: Hey, I tried it, it's not working.. I think it's because echo wraps string with quotes ("") making <h1> tag become plain text instead of html element